# Vue3.2 in a group of checkboxes, check/uncheck only two

Tags: vuejs3

I have a group of seven checkboxes in Vue3.2 with Components API. Two of the checkboxes I want to have a behavior that only allows one or the other to be checked, or neither to be checked.

Script setup:

```
const schema = [
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "one",
        label: "One",
    },    
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "two",
        label: "Two",
    },
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "three",
        label: "Three",
    },
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "four",
        label: "Four",
    },
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "five",
        label: "Five",
    },
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "six",
        label: "Six",
    },
    {
        $formkit: "checkbox",
        name: "seven",
        label: "Seven",
    }
];
const data = ref({
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false,
    four: false,   // Uncheck when six is checked
    five: false,
    six: false,    // Uncheck when four is checked
    seven: false
});
```

Template below works accordingly with v-else-if, I am just focused on the checkboxes:

```
<template>
<FormKit type="step" name="category" v-model="data">
   <FormKitSchema :schema="schema" :data="data"></FormKitSchema>
   <FormKit type="group" name="first" v-if="data.one"></FormKit>
   <FormKit type="group" name="second" v-if="data.two"></FormKit>
   <FormKit type="group" name="third" v-if="data.three"></FormKit>
   <FormKit type="group" name="fourth" v-if="data.four"></FormKit>
   <FormKit type="group" name="sixth" v-else-if="data.six"></FormKit>
   <FormKit type="group" name="fifth" v-if="data.five"></FormKit>
   <FormKit type="group" name="seventh" v-if="data.seven"></FormKit>
</Formkit>
</template>
```

Can this be done by adding v-model in schema for the two checkboxes and then using computed or watch to handle that change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. There needs to be a watch for each checkbox that needs watching. Also wasn't getting it at first as I was watching data.six and data.four; they both need to be data.value.four and data.value.six. Also need to ensure that watch is in the vue import.

```
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

watch(() => data.value.six, (nv) => {
  if (nv) {
    data.value.four = false;
  }
});

watch(() => data.value.four, (nv) => {
  if (nv) {
    data.value.six = false;
  }
});
```

This allows either checkbox to be checked or none, but not both!